# Rewrite a condition on a $3\times3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Consider the $3\times 3$ matrix
$$
A\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1-\mu_1'& \mu_1-\mu_1'-c & \mu_1-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\mu_1+a-\mu_1'& \mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c & \mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'& \mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c & \mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\mu_1, \mu_1', a, b, c, d$ are real numbers and $a,b,c,d$ are strictly positive.

Notice that
$$
R_2=R_1+a\\
R_3=R_1+a+b\\
C_2=C_1-c\\
C_3=C_1-c-d
$$
where $R_1,R_2,R_3,C_1,C_2,C_3$ are respectively the three columns and the 3 rows of $A$.

---

**Claim that I have already shown:** Assume

(1) $a\neq b,c\neq d$

(2) $\mu_1,\mu_1',a,b,c,d$ are such that, when ordering the elements of $A$ from smallest to largest, the obtained ordered sequence of points is symmetric around zero.
E.g., suppose that $\mu_1,\mu_1',a,b,c,d$ are such that $A$ contains only $3$ **distinct** elements which we denote by $\eta_1<\eta_2<\eta_3$. Then, assumption (2) states that
$
\eta_1=-\eta_3$ and $
\eta_2=0$.

Then $\mu_1=\mu_1', a=c, b=d$. In other words, $C_1=-R_1$,$C_2=-R_2$, $C_3=-R_3$.

---

**Question:** can we rewrite $(1)$ [or state sufficient conditions for $(1)$] in a way that involves some "well known" operations on the matrix $A$? E.g., as a sort of rank condition? Or as a sort of  determinant condition? Or as a sort of linear independence condition?

---

**More details (not sure they are needed)**

I have developed the proof of my claim above in a "very constructive" way which somehow prevents me to understand if there is any " mathematically deeper" meaning of assumption (1) that can be stated in terms of the properties of the matrix $A$.

Let me report here a summary of the proof of my claim above.

**1)** First of all notice that we can establish a partial order of the elements of $A$, i.e.
$$
A\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1-\mu_1'&<& \mu_1-\mu_1'-c &<&  \mu_1-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\wedge && \wedge && \wedge\\
\mu_1+a-\mu_1'&<&  \mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c &<&  \mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\wedge && \wedge && \wedge\\
\mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'&<&  \mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c &<&  \mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**2)** Let $\eta_1<\eta_2<...<\eta_m$ denote the ordered distinct elements of $A$, where $3\leq m\leq 9$ and
$$
\begin{cases}
\eta_1\equiv \mu_1-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\eta_m\equiv \mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'\\
\end{cases}
$$
Under assumption (2), $\eta_1=-\eta_m$, that is
$$
(\diamond)\hspace{1cm}\mu_1-\mu_1'=\frac{c+d-a-b}{2}
$$

**3)** The candidates for $\eta_2$ are
$$
\begin{cases}
\mu_1-\mu_1'-c\\
\mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c-d\\
\end{cases}
$$
and the candidates for $\eta_{m-1}$ are
$$
\begin{cases}
\mu_1+a-\mu_1'\\
\mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c
\end{cases}
$$
We know that
$$
{\small
\begin{aligned}
\eta_1<\min\{\mu_1-\mu_1'-c, 
& \mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c-d\} \leq  \max\{\mu_1-\mu_1'-c,  
\mu_1+a-\mu_1'-c-d\} \\
& \leq 
\min\{\mu_1+a-\mu_1',\mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c\} \leq \max\{\mu_1+a-\mu_1',\mu_1+a+b-\mu_1'-c\}<\eta_m
\end{aligned}}
$$
We can show that, under assumption (2) and using $(\diamond)$, this implies
$$
\min\{a,d\}=\min\{b,c\}
$$

**4)** Under assumption (1), $\min\{a,d\}=\min\{b,c\}$ reduces to two cases
$$
\text{case i): } b=d<a,d<c
$$
and
$$
\text{case ii): } a=c<b,c<d
$$

**5)**
We find $\eta_1,...,\eta_m$ under case i) and show that assumption (2) implies $\mu_1=\mu_1'$ and $a=c$.

**6)**
We find $\eta_1,...,\eta_m$ under case ii) and show that assumption (2) implies $\mu_1=\mu_1'$ and $b=d$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for asking clarifications. Regarding your first question, I have tried to rewritten assumption (2). Is it more clear now?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Regarding your second statement on the symmetry of the matrix $A$: how can it be that $A$ is symmetric when $a=c,b=d$? When $a=c,b=d$, then, for example, $A(2,1)=A(1,2)$ that is $\mu_1+c-\mu_1'=\mu_1-\mu_1'-c$ which is impossible given $c>0$.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it can't be $a=-c,b=-d$ because $a,b,c,d$ are strictly positive. Hence, the matrix $A$ cannot be symmetric.